# Pentose phosphate pathway mechanism: glucose-6-phosphate converting to 6-phosphoglucono-delta-lactone

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am trying to write a mechanism of the first step in the pentose phosphate pathway where G6P is converted to PPP with cofactor NADP+ and His residue.
I wrote this first mechanism where I did not open the ring.
[image]

I did not receive a full score for that (7.5 out of 8). So I did my second attempt where I tried to open the ring. However, I am not sure how to proceed from there to reform the ring, or if the ring opening step is correct or not. As the comment mentioned this mechanism is not balanced. So I made a new edit.
[image]

Edit:
Here is the new attempt:
[image]

Comment: Your ring-opening reaction is not balanced.

Comment: Lactones are cyclic esters. When you open the ring, you get a carboxylic acid (this is a hydrolysis, in contrast to opening a sugar ring). With 7.5 of 8 points for your first attempt, you might be almost correct and lost 0.5 points for some detail you got wrong. Maybe there is another active site residue that you are not showing?

Comment: @Karsten My professor left a note "OK" on the page. So I am thinking the mechanism is not rigorous enough. And the only thing I can think of is I should open the ring first. And only His residue was provided in the problem. When you say "hydrolysis", so there should be a water molecule leaving when I open the ring?

Comment: @ananta Ah, I see it! I have written a new mechanism. Could you check it please?

Comment: The reaction seems balanced now. Also, I recommend removing the previous (incorrect) mechanism entirely so new readers don't get confused. Also note the names "D-glucopyranose 6-phosphate(2-)" and "6-O-phosphonato-D-glucono-1,5-lactone(2-)" from [M-CSA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/m-csa/entry/843/)

Comment: Pentose phosphate pathway (PPP) AKA pentose phosphate shunt is the name of the reaction mechanism (pathway) and not the product.

Comment: Maybe they just wanted you to deprotonate the histidine as the last step to regenerate the enzyme to its initial state and get the stoichiometry right (NADPH + $\ce{H+}$).

Answer (score 1):

#### Reaction Mechanism

[BioLibreTexts](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Biochemistry/Fundamentals_of_Biochemistry_(Jakubowski_and_Flatt)/02%3A_Unit_II-_Bioenergetics_and_Metabolism/13%3A_Glycolysis_Gluconeogenesis_and_the_Pentose_Phosphate_Pathway/13.04%3A_Pentose_Phosphate_Pathway_of_Glucose_Oxidation) shows the following mechanism for the reaction

$$\ce{D-glucopyranose 6-phosphate(2-) \\-> 6-O-phosphonato-D-glucono-1,5-lactone(2-)}
$$

[image: Mechanism of Leuconostoc mesenteroides glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase. Conversion of glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase (G6P) to 6-phosphoglucono-delta-lactone (PPP)]

Note that this mechanism was sourced from [M-CSA](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/m-csa/entry/843/)$^1$.

#### Points to note

1. I doubt if the ring (completely) opens during the reaction.
2. $\ce{NADPH}$ is produced from $\ce{NADP+}$ during the reaction.
3. $\ce{His240-methylimidazole}$ moiety abstracts a proton from the substrate, eliminating a hydride that is added to $\ce{NADP+}$) and returns to original (deprotonated form) upon abstraction of the proton by a water molecule.

Regarding point 2, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotinamide_adenine_dinucleotide_phosphate) states:

> NADPH is produced from NADP+. The major source of NADPH in animals and
> other non-photosynthetic organisms is the pentose phosphate pathway,
> by glucose-6-phosphate dehydrogenase (G6PDH) in the first step.

Regarding point 3, the $\ce{His240-methylimidazole}$ moiety acts catalytically, undergoing serial protonation and deprotonation.

[image: catalytic nature of methylimidazole moiety in pentose phosphate phosphate]

#### References

1. *Mechanism and Catalytic Site Atlas (M-CSA): a database of enzyme reaction mechanisms and active sites*, Antonio J. M. Ribeiro, Gemma L. Holliday, Nicholas Furnham, Jonathan D. Tyzack, Katherine Ferris1 and Janet M. Thornton *Nucleic Acids Research*, 2018, Vol. 46, Database issue, [10.1093/nar/gkx1012](https://doi.org/10.1093/nar/gkx1012)

Comment: His 240 is one of the amino acid residues of the protein. 240 is the 240th building block in the protein. Here, they are showing the side chain only, attached to the label “his 240”. This is common (if not entirely logical) nomenclature in biochemistry.